# Create a bot that recognizes the right moment to press 'E' in Python

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

[What needs to be identified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28UMm.png)[Right time to press 'E'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZJxb.png)
I'm trying to make a bot that presses 'E' to automate a fishing game, in the photos I show what it looks like when you can press it (it's in red), I would like to know how to identify this color change, so that the bot press 'E' automatically.

I tried to do it, but it doesn't recognize the color. Here is the code I was testing:

```
import cv2
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image

fishing_image_rgb = fishing_image.convert("RGB")
pixel_fishing_image = fishing_image_rgb.getpixel((10,20))

print(pixel_fishing_image)

# Color in RGB
color = (89, 42, 42)

while True:
    ps = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(1267, 833, 300, 100))
    ps.save('PS.png')
    ps.show()

    # Look for the color in the image
    if ps is not None:
        if color in ps.getcolors():
            print("Color found")
            pyautogui.press('e')
        else:
            print("Couldn't find the color")
            sleep(0.1) 
    else:
        print("Unable to capture screen.")
```

I tried this code but it didn't work. I tried this code but it didn't work. I tested with the exact color, the print screen is working, but it does not identify the color.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
# x and y are the coordinates of the pixel in the screenshot you want to know the position of.
color = ps.getpixel((x,y))
if color[0] == 89 and color[1] == 42 and color[2] == 42:
    print("Color found!")
    pyautogui.press('e')
```

If it doesn't work, maybe the colors you have are not exact, so try modifying the if statement this way:

```
if color[0] > 84 and color[0] < 94:
    if color[1] > 37 and color[1] < 47:
        if color[2] > 37 and color[2] < 47:
            pyautogui.press('e')
```